# UIWebView never displays scroll bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I have a UIWebView displaying content of multiple pages in length.

The problem is this: a scroll bar never appears while the user is scrolling the content vertically (unlike in Safari, or in other apps using what appears to be UIWebView). I can't see any way to control this programmatically.

Behaviour is the same on iOS 3.1 through 4.2, on both iPhone and iPad, both device and simulator.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the `WebView` is not slightly bigger than its parent?  If it's a bit too big the scroll bars might actually be there but off the screen.

Comment: Well, if there's a badge for the daftest question ever asked, I guess I've earned it. Yes - that was the answer. Somehow I had acquired an extra 9px of width in Interface Builder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[(UIScrollView*)[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

Comment: This depends on implementation details, and may break in future versions, or get your application rejected during the App Store approval process.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - however, I still see no scroll bar while scrolling. The docs say that the default for showsVerticalScrollIndicator is YES, so in theory I shouldn't have to set this explicitly, right?

Comment: @StephenT: Yes, it should be YES as a default value.